# Jssor slider change mouse pointer

Tags: jssor

Using Jssor slider how do I change the mouse pointer to something different than the arrows up.down/left/right. Is it possible to have no change at all when mouse hovers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you.
Please find and modify code here

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move....
```

Answer (score 1):

add to css:

```
    .jssor_slider_slides {
    cursor: default !important;
}
```